# How to connect to this wifi

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I'm currently using **Ubuntu 12.04.3**... I have a **BroadCom 4313 Wireless card**... I have installed the proprietary driver from **additional drivers** application.

I'm able to connect to wifi in my home. But, in my college they have some firewall and need to configure their settings...

The details are in the intranet. So, I have attached it in Google Docs.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-mVaIx1Fkv5ZwjkucbJp2lPFn_Az9DUN_lAEiQJWzKQ/pub

I even tried changing some settings. But, i'm unable to connect. (I haven't edited any code in ubuntu).

Can you please help me to configure my laptop to connect to wifi in my college??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does your college allow some `Proxy` to use Internet Connection?

Comment: no. No proxy used

Comment: Please run the terminal command: lspci -nn. Is your wireless device 14e4:4727?

Comment: yes. It is chili555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. The problem was **Wireless N** wasn't working. I solved it by using the following commands:

```
sudo -i
apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Now, wifi works just fine :)

Thanks others for your recommendations :)

Answer (score 1):

Click the Network Manager icon in the panel, select 'Edit Connections', in the next window, select the wireless tab, and click 'Add'...

- then give the new connection a name, and fill in the SSID:

[image: Wireless tab]

- click the Wireless Security tab, change the settings according to the image below, and add the username and password

[image: Wireless security tab]

Hope it works.

Comment: I did it. But, no use. It starts asking for username and password everytime. I can't get connected

Comment: I've noticed that the correct SSID is Kongu_Wifi and not Kongu_wifi.

Comment: ya. but, i figured out the solution. Thanks for your step by step instructions :)