# unable to connect to internet on ubuntu 13.10 but works fine on windows 7 on same computer

Tags: wireless, internet

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 7. Everything works perfectly fine except for the internet. In edit connections it just shows an ethernet connection when I boot onto Windows 7 the wireless connection works fine but it doesn't work in Ubuntu. I tried creating a connection but it didn't work either.

Comment: Try with this procedure: http://askubuntu.com/a/339737/62483

Comment: What is your wireless card? Can you see any networks, or just not connect? Does the Ethernet work? Run: `sudo lshw -c network` in the terminal and paste the output into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue a couple of times and I solved it by changing the password's encryption type. In Edit Connections, click on your WiFi network, then Edit, then head to the WiFi Security tab and double-check if it is set onto the correct encryption, e.g. WPA2 if that's what you have.

You can check what encryption is used on your Win7 install in the Network PrefPan. I hope this helps!

R.